# Extract "n" rows with least variation across samples

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

An example dataframe:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b = c(1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5)
c = c(2,4,6,7,9,20)
d = c(1,1,1,1.2,1,1.3)
e = c(6,9,100,20,52,61)
gene = c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5","gene6")
df = data.frame(gene,a,b,c,d,e)
```

Hi,
From the dataframe, I would like to extract "n" number of rows/genes (say, 2) which are most stable across the dataset i.e, with minimal variation in intensities across the samples. How can I do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: You define `minimal variation` = mean absolute deviation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Base R** This uses onlyu base R:

```
n <- 3
df[head(order(apply(df[-1], 1, sd)), n), ]
```

giving:

```
   gene a   b c   d  e
1 gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6
2 gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9
4 gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20
```

**2) dplyr/apply** or using dplyr we have the following.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 3
df %>%
   arrange(select(., -gene) %>% apply(1, sd)) %>%
   top_n(-n)
```

**3) dplyr/rowwise** or another dplyr solution, this one using `rowwise`.  Note that dot within `do` refers to the current row as a list and dot within `{...}` refers to the input of the expression it is in. Omit the `select(-sd)` line if you want to leave the `sd` column in.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 3
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   do(as.data.frame(.) %>% { mutate(., sd = select(., -gene) %>% sd(.))}) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(sd) %>%
   select(-sd) %>%
   top_n(-n)
```

**4) dplyr/purrr**  This is the same as (2) except it uses `pmap_dbl` from purrr instead of `apply`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purr)

n <- 3
df %>%
   arrange(select(., -gene) %>% pmap_dbl(~ sd(c(...)))) %>%
   top_n(-n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked beautifully!

Comment: @ip2018. This uses standard deviation not mean absolute deviation.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck not criticising your solution but the lack of clarity on part of op (see comments). Caveat: `base::mad()` is NOT mean absolute deviation.

Comment: In place of `sd` you can use  `mad` from base for median absolute deviation or  `DescTools::MeanAD` for mean absolute deviation or define the measure yourself if you want to measure variation differently.

Comment: Tested both and `sd` works better for what I want. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `rowSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
n <- 3
df[order(rowSds(as.matrix(df[-1])))[seq_len(n)],]
#   gene a   b c   d  e
#1 gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6
#2 gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9
#4 gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   arrange(pmap_dbl(.[-1], ~ sd(c(...)))) %>% 
   slice(seq_len(n))
#   gene a   b c   d  e
#1 gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6
#2 gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9
#3 gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20
```

Or with `rowSds`

```
df %>%
     arrange(rowSds(as.matrix(.[-1]))) %>%
     slice(seq_len(n))
#   gene a   b c   d  e
#1 gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6
#2 gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9
#3 gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, order(rowSds(as.matrix(.SD)))[seq_len(n)], .SDcols = -1]]
#    gene a   b c   d  e
#1: gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6
#2: gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9
#3: gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `data.table`**

```
library(data.table)

# Helper function
meanad <- function(x) {
  sum(abs(x-mean(x)))/length(x)
}

k <- 3
topgenes <- setDT(df)[, meanad := meanad(unlist(.SD)), by = gene
                      ][order(meanad)
                        ][, as.character(head(gene, k))
                          ]

df[gene %in% topgenes]
    gene a   b c   d  e   meanad
1: gene1 1 1.0 2 1.0  6 1.304444
2: gene2 2 1.1 4 1.0  9 2.159556
3: gene4 4 1.3 7 1.2 20 4.673333
```